# Gitlab-runner cann't connect to gitlab server

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Shell demo job (just echo) can execute success.
error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.10.0 (81ab07f6)
  on shared-docker hqPeU4dFC, system ID: s_399ed16fe5dc
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:05
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Pulling docker image docker:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:432fb9e24d7063a069ef25c45c2fd203737158272d014d50e53c81c0827bac8b for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:016c45d9e31461802186e8e9aaa394f35e173a8ce913ea7195a672cdc97102f2 ...
Preparing environment
00:02
Running on runner-hqpeu4dfc-project-2-concurrent-0 via DESKTOP-QPAO8U0...
Getting source from Git repository
00:04
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/demo-group2/demo-project2/.git/
fatal: unable to access 'http://172.17.24.145:8000/demo-group2/demo-project2.git/': Failed to connect to 172.17.24.145 port 8000 after 3120 ms: Couldn't connect to server
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

gitlab.yml

```
stages:
  - testMyDocker

docker-job:
  # 11111
    stage: testMyDocker
    script: docker info
    tags:
      - docker
      - shared
```

runner config:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "shared-docker"
  url = "http://172.17.24.145:8000"
  id = 46
  token = "glrt-hqPeU4dFCj_fNBL48jcy"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-03-27T08:28:48Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0
    clone_url = "http://172.17.24.145:8000"
```

My first question, if there are any shortcomings, please guide me. Thank you!

After registering a Docker mode runner, I want to test and learn more about this mode's runner.